# Accessing an image field inside a Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So I'm trynna access the first image of the product but for some reason it's not showing.

Edit: Here's the template:

```
 {% for item in items %}
 <tr>
 <td>
<div class="product-item">
<a class="product-thumb" href="#"><img src=" 
 {{item.product.image.all.0.image.url}}" alt="{{ item.product.name }}"> 
 </a>
 <div class="product-info">
 <h4 class="product-title"><a href="#">{{item.product.name}}</a>
 </div>
 </div>
 </td>
<td class="text-center">
<p data-product={{item.product.id}} data-action="add" class="update-cart 
 arrows"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" style="color: #5bc0de;"></i></p>
<p id="quantity">{{item.quantity}}</p>
<p data-product={{item.product.id}} data-action="decrease" 
 class="update-cart arrows"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" style="color: 
 #5bc0de;"></i></p>
 <td class="text-center text-lg text- 
  medium">&nbsp;${{item.product.price}} 
 </td>
 <td class="text-center text-lg text- 
 medium">${{item.get_total|floatformat:2}}</td>
 <td class="text-center"><button data-product={{item.product.id}} data- 
 action='remove' class="btn btn-danger update-cart remove-from- 
 cart">Remove</button></td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

First these are the models that I have:

```
  class Product(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
        stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', null=True)
        image = models.ManyToManyField('Image', blank=True)
        serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images/')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

As you can see they're connected. Reason why is because each object has multiple images. I only want to display the first image. So here's the view:

```
def cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        try:
           cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])
        except:
            cart = {}   
        print('Cart:', cart)
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total': 0, 'get_cart_items': 0, 'shipping': True} 
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items'] 
        for i in cart:
            cartItems += cart[i]['quantity']
            product = Product.objects.get(id=i)
            total = (product.price * cart[i]['quantity'])

            order['get_cart_total'] += total
            order['get_cart_items'] += cart[i]['quantity']
            item = {
                'product':{
                    'id': product.id,
                    'name': product.name,
                    'price': product.price,
                    'imageURL': product.image.first().image.url
                },
                'quantity':cart[i]['quantity'],
                'get_total': total
            }
            items.append(item)
```

In this view, when the user is authenticated, I'm able to display the product's info with no problems in the html. I used a for loop to loop through the "items" and in the image section I said: `src="{{item.product.image.all.0.image.url}}"` which works fine. But when the user is just a guest which means the view goes to the else statement and starts looking for info from the item object, the image does not get displayed and instead is displayed like a broken image.

I've tried modifying this

`'imageURL': product.image.first().image.url`

to this

`'imageURL': product.image.all()[0].image.url`

but nothing worked so far.

Any help is appreciated, I'm slowly losing my sanity over this dumb problem

Comment: can you share the template of the code and also how you render the template (the last part of the view)?

Comment: return {'cartItems':cartItems ,'order':order, 'items':items} This is how I render it in the view

and the template is in the op since it's too long to be posted here

Comment: Note this `product = Product.objects.get(id=i)` is also a terrible performance. Try to build a single query which will get all you need in one run. It is unusual that products are connected with images via M2M relation (may be you meant a regular FK from images to products) but you can get all top-1 images in a single query as well.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that one of those will work:
`product.image_set.[0].image.url`
`product.images.all()[0].image.url`

If it will work I will try to make it more efficient using `earliest('id')` or something similiar.

reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#earliest